# Can I realize the exclude fields function in Serializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my serializers.py, I created a UserListSerializer:

```
class UserListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = [
            'password',
        ]
```

I want to realize the exclude fields function, but failed.

> AssertionError at /api/users/list/
>   Cannot set both 'fields' and 'exclude' options on serializer UserListSerializer.

Is it possible to realize this function, because the fields is too much?

Comment: you can just remove `fields = '__all__'` from your `Meta`

Comment: What is unclear about that error message?

Comment: so, sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot use both fields and exclude in the Meta Class of your serializer

instead try this

```
class UserListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = [
            'password',
        ]
```